# How to fetch data on Firebase every 5 seconds?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing Android app - users can track location of others people. Every users sends their gps coordinates every 5 seconds, but fetching data about others users is making every time when location is save in database, so firebase trigger `onChildChanged` function in listener. I want to fetch data every 5 seconds also, otherwise it will expensive.

Assume we have three users with my app:

User A start sending his location at 5:00:03.
User B start sending his location at 5:00:06 - three seconds later than user A.

At 5:00:08 user A update coordinates, user B do the same at 5:00:11.

User C started listen for a change of locations at 5:00:00.
At 5:00:03 - receive update about User A.
At 5:00:03 - receive info about user B.
5:00:08 - receive update about User A.
5:00:11 - receive info about user B.

In a 11 seconds User C receive many updates, function `onChildChanged` on app of user C work every time, when location of any user is changed.

Expected behavior would be like this:

5:00:00 - user C started listening.
5:00:05 - user C receive info about user A location.
5:00:10 - user C receive info about User A and User B.

So I need receive data every 5 seconds instead of every data change.

I am wondering, I have to add new listener every five seconds, then fetch data, and remove listener? Or I need use firebase functions?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the listeners to check for child changed?

Comment: Firebase use Realtime database. It means any modification in Firebase Database will reflect into your app same time.

Comment: Yes, Firebase is expensive if you exceed limit of queries.

Comment: Why don't you write to Firebase every 5 seconds with the people's locations, that way `onDataChange` is triggered every 5 seconds?

Comment: That is wrote but every user can send location in a different time, so, onDataChange will be triggered very often when many users will start updating gps coordinates.

Comment: @DanielKozak You seem to have an idea of how Firebase will behave for your use-case that other folks here either don't understand or disagree with. The best you can do is show in code how the naïve version of a listener would work, and then express what your concern with that code is. That way we're all looking at code, and can reason about that code, instead of discussing behavior in the abstract.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to call an API after every 5 minutes. You can send user location change event from one device to server then check it on your application. You can use listeners.

Or use ***.keepSynced*** query function.

```
final Query query = firebase.child("node1").child("node2");
query.keepSynced(true);
```